# Retain data in angular on a page reload without using storage?

Tags: angular

I have a JWT token that I wanted to save in angular app but I have some issues with storing it in session Storage or local storage as it does not get deleted automatically on the same browser/tab. So is there any way I can save the token and use it without having to worry about page reload and losing data?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean does not get deleted? If you save the token in sessionStorage, then even when user refreshes the same page the token will be there. The sessionStorage exists only within the current browser tab. Another tab with the same page will have a different storage. The data survives page refresh, but not closing/opening the tab. Once user closes the tab, sessionStorage is cleared.

LocalStorage will be cleaned when user clears browsing data manually. LocalStorage data is shared between all tabs and windows from the same origin. The data does not expire. It remains after the browser restart and even OS reboot.

There aren't many other options for saving data on client's machine and having it survive a refresh. Well... there are cookies, caches etc. But the idea is pretty much the same. Out of all the options, sessionStorage and localStorage are quite easy to access and would fit your scenario perfectly.

Saving your token to sessionStorage would make sense. You get to use/update the token the whole duration of the users session. And it will be automatically removed when user closes the tab.

```js
window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```